# How to save each click that the user gives on the map and access them individually? Shiny Leaflet R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

```r
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map',width = "1331",height = "400"))
  
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    m<-leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))%>%
      setView(lng =-73.935242, lat =40.730610, zoom= 12)})
  
  
  observe({  click = input$map_click
  if(is.null(click))
    return()
  else
    clicks=data.frame(click[1:2])
  leafletProxy("map") %>%
    addMarkers(data = clicks) #Adds a marker on each click

    
  clicklist <<- reactiveVal(list()) # empty list
  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    temp <<- clicklist() # get the list of past clicks 
    temp[[length(temp)+1]] <<- click[1:2] # add this click to the list
    clicklist(temp)
    print(clicklist)})  #show on the console  lat and lng

  })
    }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]
*an image to attract your attention*

Console:

```r
reactiveVal: [1] "40.74778, -73.97953" 
reactiveVal: [1] "40.73191, -73.99704" 
reactiveVal: [1] "40.73191, -73.99704" "40.73191, -73.99704"
```

**The code above saves only the last user click on the map in the "clicklist" object, and repeats it as many times as the user clicks on the map.**

```r
>clicklist
reactiveVal: [1] "40.72931, -73.99326" "40.72931, -73.99326" "40.72931, -73.99326"
```

The object class is reactivevalue.

```r
> class(clicklist)
[1] "reactiveVal" "reactive"
```

> How to save each click and access them individually?

## Expected output

```r
>clicklist
[[1]]
[1]40.74778 -73.97953
[[2]]
[1]40.73191 -73.99704 

>clicklist[1]
[1] 40.74778, -73.97953

>clicklist[1][[1]][1]
[1] 40.74778

>clicklist[1][[1]][2]
-73.97953

>clicklist[2]
[[1]]
[1]  40.73191 -73.99704

>clicklist[2][[1]][1]
[1] 40.73191

> clicklist[2][[1]][2]
[1] -73.99704
```

Comment: try `unlist` when you add the new input to the list. Also, do `clicklist()` (with paranthesis) instead of `clicklist` in `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gives the expected output, your expected output is a list of vectors but `input$map_click` gives a list, a named list to be exact. To convert it to a vector, we used `unlist`, since your desired output doesn't have names in the vector as well, we used `unname` to remove the names. Also, if your code is breaking on app initialization due to the unavailability of some input, use `req` to have observers wait for that input. This is one of the recommended approaches to handle this kind of behavior. `<<` is not recommended in shiny apps and is to be used very carefully. In your code, it was actually redundant.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map',width = "1331",height = "400"))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    m <-leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))%>%
      setView(lng =-73.935242, lat =40.730610, zoom= 12)})


  observe({
    req(input$map_click)
    clicks <- data.frame(input$map_click[1:2])
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      addMarkers(data = clicks) #Adds a marker on each click
  })

  clicklist <- reactiveVal(list()) # empty list

  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    temp <- clicklist() # get the list of past clicks 
    temp[[length(temp)+1]] <- unname(unlist(click[1:2])) # add this click to the list
    clicklist(temp)
    print(clicklist())
  })  #show on the console  lat and lng
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```